# bumping the compileSdkVersion

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXxAJ.png)

Just running my program
I want my program to run normally

Comment: just... do what it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the path which is mentioned and change the settings as follows

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
}
```